# how to get all child itemvalues in list in flex3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i'm new for flex...
we can the length by using getnumber but
i want to get all item values in the list and to display the item values in the alert box one by one... is it possibile?
thank's

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get them directly from your list's DataProvider (which might be an ArrayCollection or a XML object?)